# Save File Dialog Windows App

Tags: winforms, savefiledialog

Question 1:
How do I suppress Cancel button click event of Save As dialog box to make sure that my users click save button only?

Question 2:
How do I prevent users from creating New folder while Save As dialog box is open?

Question 3:
How do I prevent users from changing the current folders path while Save As dialog box is open?

Your help is much appreciated in advance

Kindest Regards
Lucky Khoza

Comment: Probably easiest way to meet all requirements you've posted is not to use standart save file dialog, but implement your own dialog window and use it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Windows Hooks and trap the messages sent to the dialog box and take appropriate action. [EasyHook](https://easyhook.github.io/) can help you in developing the hook.

The following [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19566/Extend-OpenFileDialog-and-SaveFileDialog-the-easy) can also help you